# Magento 2.4.4 Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page

Tags: backend, magento2.4.4

Hello i read that issue was solved in 2.4.4 version however i still display it in admin area
[image]

I already change max_input_vars = 10000 but not fixed the problem.
Any other way?
Thanks

Comment: I think it's related to session time.

Comment: Okay it's an important problem or can i ignore it? because i can't see any particular issue on it

Comment: If you are facing same issue on staging server then you can disable it.

Comment: Admin > Store > Configuration > Advanced > Admin(tab) > Security > 

ecret Key to URLs = no

Answer (score 0):

This is not a particular bug in Magento,There are many cause for this type error

In Most cases you can resolve it.

- Increase Max_input_vars value.
- Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Try with update base url.

```
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
```